# Fatal error compiling: tools.jar not found: C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_151\..\lib\tools.jar

Tags: java, eclipse

am getting following error while building Maven project

Error :

```
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:2.5.1:compile (default-compile) @ SpringRestExample ---
[WARNING] File encoding has not been set, using platform encoding Cp1252, i.e. build is platform dependent!
[INFO] Compiling 3 source files to D:\downloaded\SpringRestExample\target\classes
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 3.558s
[INFO] Finished at: Mon Dec 25 20:02:18 IST 2017
[INFO] Final Memory: 11M/94M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:2.5.1:compile (default-compile) on project SpringRestExample: Fatal error compiling: tools.jar not found: C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_151\..\lib\tools.jar -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:2.5.1:compile (default-compile) on project SpringRestExample: Fatal error compiling
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:217)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:84)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:59)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.singleThreadedBuild(LifecycleStarter.java:183)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:161)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:320)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:156)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:537)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:196)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:141)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:290)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:230)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:409)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:352)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoExecutionException: Fatal error compiling
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.AbstractCompilerMojo.execute(AbstractCompilerMojo.java:683)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.CompilerMojo.execute(CompilerMojo.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:101)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:209)
    ... 19 more
Caused by: org.codehaus.plexus.compiler.CompilerException: tools.jar not found: C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_151\..\lib\tools.jar
    at org.codehaus.plexus.compiler.javac.JavacCompiler.createJavacClass(JavacCompiler.java:987)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.compiler.javac.JavacCompiler.getJavacClass(JavacCompiler.java:944)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.compiler.javac.JavacCompiler.compileInProcess(JavacCompiler.java:520)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.compiler.javac.JavacCompiler.compile(JavacCompiler.java:167)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.AbstractCompilerMojo.execute(AbstractCompilerMojo.java:678)
    ... 22 more
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
```

I set   JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_151

[changed project properties as](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VtwJR.jpg)

I tried changing everything even though i re installed jdk but its not working please help to resolve this.

Comment: You have to use a JDK and NOT and JRE...

Comment: will try with jdk

Comment: Furthermore you should check why the tools jar is needed in your build?